# Searching for strongly connected components using neo4j

Tags: java, algorithm, neo4j

I'm trying to implement SCC algorithm using neo4j for storing graph.

Here is my implementation of DFS:

```
void dfs(GraphDatabaseService g, Node node, long counter) {

    Transaction tx = g.beginTx();
    node.setProperty("explored", true);
    tx.success();
    tx.finish();
    System.out.println("Exporing node " + node.getProperty("name") + "with depth " + counter);

    Iterator<Relationship> it = node.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING, RelTypes.KNOWS).iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Node end = it.next().getEndNode();
        if (!(boolean) end.getProperty("explored"))
            dfs(g, end, ++counter);
    }  
}
```

It throws StackOverflowError. Well, obvious reason is that depth of recursion is getting too big.
But maybe there is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to write your own recursive DFS as Neo4j provides that out of the box. I'd rewrite your method in the following fashion:

```
void dfs(GraphDatabaseService g, Node node) {

    //neo4j provided traversal API
    TraversalDescription traversalDescription = new TraversalDescriptionImpl()
            .depthFirst()
            .relationships(RelTypes.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING)
            .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL);

    Iterable<Node> nodesInComponent = traversalDescription.traverse(node).nodes();

    //uses GraphAware to save some lines of code
    new IterableInputBatchTransactionExecutor<>(g, 1000, nodesInComponent, new UnitOfWork<Node>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(GraphDatabaseService database, Node input) {
            System.out.println("Exploring node " + input.getProperty("name"));
            if (!(boolean) input.getProperty("explored", false)) {
                input.setProperty("explored", true);
            }
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

The first four lines use pure Neo4j API and retrieve a lazy iterable that gets you the nodes you need.

The remaining lines write the "explored" property in batches of 1000 rather than in separate transactions, for performance reasons. For brewity, the [GraphAware](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) framework is used (disclaimer: I'm its author), but it could well be written with a few more lines of pure Neo4j code.

I've tried with 10,000 nodes (a single connected component), took about 26 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually already solved the problem with representing graph as a list of nodes with every vertex knowing positions of adjacent vertices in the list.
It saved me memory. But gaved me another stackoverflow exception. I solved it with increasing stack of java in eclipse.

But the right way to do it, I think still would be with some graph database.

I knew about dfs in neo4j, but I wanted to implement it myself in educational purposes.